# How can I insert xml in a document using python-docx?

Tags: xml, docx, python-docx

I am fairly new to python-docx and I just read that one can manipulate the xml somehow.

I want to give a paragraph a background color on the full width of the page. But I could not find an option for that. Therefore I thought that could somehow append the appropriate xml to the paragraph, but I do not know how.

Best regards

Comment: A docx file is (largely/basically/simplified, for your purposes) an XML file, and python-docx "somehow manipulates" this XML *for you*: the library is so you don't have to do so yourself. But what you can do with it is limited by what the library includes; if there is no function or attribute exposed, then you cannot do it through python-docx.

Comment: Yes, but if I understood that correctly, then there must be a way to pass some additional xml data and to enhance the docx file with that. And I guess this means that there is some syntax I have to learn and also some xml reference. And if I had that, I should be able to pass that background color (see my initial question) to the corresponding paragraph.

Comment: For example, this part of the docs (https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/analysis/features/text/paragraph-format.html) shows many information about the underlying xml. I just do not know how to use it.